# PhoneGap+Backbone.js: cannot display a list of phone contacts

Tags: cordova, backbone.js

I have a PhoneGap app that I use Backbone js to manage models, views and routers.

I have a view that displays a list of phone contacts.

Phone contacts are retrieved with PhoneGap API.

the **contact view template** is this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="contacttemplate">
            <div>
            <dl>
                <dt><%= displayName %></dt>
            </dl>
            </div>
        </script>
```

the **render** function of the view is this:

```
render: function () {
        var template = _.template($("#contacttemplate").html(), 
JSON.stringify(this.model));
        $(this.el).html(template);
        return this;
    }
```

where the model is of type [Contact](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contact)

But I receive the following error

> ReferenceError:'displayName' is undefined

what can be wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `model.toJSON()` to get json data of a model's attributes.

```
var template = _.template($("#contacttemplate").html(), this.model.toJSON());
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON

Comment: It gave me the following error: TypeError: Unable to get property 'toJSON' of undefined or null reference

Comment: How and  where you setting the `this.model` parameter

Comment: If your Model itself is undefined, issue is elsewhere.

Comment: The model is not defined as a Backbone model, it's a PhoneGap Contact object